# Android Room Migration - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: android, database, kotlin, migration

I am trying to add a column to an existing table in the database. The column is type `ArrayList<Date>` I wrote a migration step, increased database version number, and added the migration. When I run the migration (run the app), I get the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter value

when attempting to read data from that table.

I have tried following the steps here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929

I have also tested with other data types, and it has migrated successfully. Seems like the issue is adding Lists or `ArrayList`s.

```
val MIGRATION_2_3 = object : Migration(2, 3) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL(
            "ALTER TABLE product ADD COLUMN ingredients TEXT"
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're altering a table without setting a default value. Therefore the default is null for all rows already present within the table. Since you require the *Kotlin* property to be non-null, you receive the `IllegalArgumentException`.

To resolve the issue, you'd have to alter the table to contain a default value for `ingredients` and declare it non-null as well.

```
val MIGRATION_2_3 = object : Migration(2, 3) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL(
            "ALTER TABLE product ADD COLUMN ingredients TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''"
        )
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could make the `ingredients` *Kotlin* property nullable.

Comment: Hey @tynn, thank you for your response, I actually want the `ingredients` property to be nullable.